# How to change databases during a single session

Tags: php, mysql

I need to achieve the functionality where users can change databases on the fly. Once changed, the current database will be used across all php files making db calls.

So, I am trying to find the best solution to switch and remember the current database params during a single session. This is what I am doing at the moment:

1) php connection files **conn1.php, conn2.php, conn3.php** etc. containing different database connection parameters (name, password etc - **$hostname**, **$username** and so on).

2) when a user changes the database, the current database code is saved as a session variable $currDB.

3) All files that contains db calls, have a db connection switch on the top:

```
switch ($currDB){
     case 1:
          require_once('conn1.php');
          break;
     case 2:
          require_once('conn2.php');
          break;
    ........
}
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
```

Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same functionality of switching databases based on the user selection? I am not sure if maintaining session vars across multiple files would be the best option.

Any better ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Create a function that returns a required connection by its name and store all the current connections in the function's static variable. Would use it like: `$mysqli = getConnectionById('name_of_connection');`

Comment: why do you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: I have had this requirement quite often: Think e.g. of a single instance of data mining tool running on a dev, a test and a production DB

Comment: Because each database contains identical tables for a single financial data provider (about 100 tables). It is more complicated to rename tables and keep a single db than switching databases, because they already come with an identical structure.

Comment: you can use a framework with multiple connections at once then you can query tables in this manner dbname.tablename.columnname

Comment: Correct, but where should I keep the currently selected dbname across different files? We are getting back to storing dbnames as session vars.

Comment: one file stores all of the dbnames in frameworks that's usually a config file or a db file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend, you do something like

- get $currentDB from the session or user input
- sanitize it to an int, either via `(int)` or e.g. `is_numeric()` followed by `abs(round(..))` on very old PHP versions

now just `@require_once("conn$currentDB.php");` and check for errors.

Last step is to put this into `conn.php` and include it from all consumers.

Comment: Thanks - very similar to what I am doing now. I am trying to get rid of session variables, if possible. I had some issues in the past when sessions were broken. If I cannot find anything better, session is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tend to put all the connection details into a single array, included from a single file or some other sort of configuration. Equally, you could also name them, 'live', 'dev', 'live-1', or whatever you like.

```
$dbDetails = array(
    1 => array('hostname' => 'localhost',
               'username' => 'blah',
               # ... etc ... ),
    2 => array('hostname' => 'localhost',
               'username' => 'blah',
               # ... password & database ... ),
);
if (!isset($currDB, $dbDetails[$currDB])) {
    die('unknown DB connection ID');
}
$db = $dbDetails[$currDB];
$mysqli = new mysqli($db['hostname'], $db['username'], $db['password'], $db['database']);
```

Comment: Where would you suggest to keep the $currDB var across different files? As a session var?

Comment: Different files in the same request all come from the same base - the first file run. If you do want to keep the same DB connection between different requests then yes, you'd keep the 'currDB' info in a session.